# API/website for blasting peptide sequence against database of all plant proteomes

Tags: proteins, blast, metagenome

I would like to blast a peptide sequence against all available plant proteome databases, i.e. a `blastp` metaproteome analysis.

What tools are available? Which database can I use?

Comment: Welcome to the site lars. You seem aware of blastp, did it not solve your problem? Or do you expect something else of blastp? Could you explain what have you tried?  (to avoid suggesting the same you have already done)

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply. So far I installed `ncbi-blast-2.7.1+`. With `makeblastdb` I generated `*.phr, *.pin, *psq` from a `fasta`. I now try `blastp` against this database. Next steps would be to compile a metadatabase from all plant proteome databases I can find.

I wonder if all of this work has already been done. Is there a website/API that I can use? I simply want to find all plant proteins which contain the amino acid sequence `TEKKRRETVEREKE`. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include this information. In addition, what sequences are in your fasta file? I think that you can download fasta files from NCBI. You  could download the sequences from plants proteins and make the database from that (if this is not already what you did)

Comment: At the moment, I work only with *arabidopsis thaliana*. Is there a plant meta-database? My main objective is to figure out in which plant species this peptide is expressed.

Comment: For example, [PPDB](http://ppdb.tc.cornell.edu) is only for *arabidopsis thaliana* and maize.

Comment: Sorry I don't work with plants (nor with blast) and I can't answer where to find such data. But add this relevant information to the question, so make it easier to those who might be able to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple BLAST on the [UniProt website](https://www.uniprot.org/blast/) does the trick (target database *plants*).

Best matches are subsequences `ETVEREKE` and `EKKRRETV` in *Green alga* and *Eelgrass* respectively.